# How to restore bluetooth PAN?

Tags: network, bluetooth, internet-sharing

I used to have bluetooth PAN by default, but i was messing around with the network interfaces.

[image]

and when removing it, i accidentally set it to not return. I've spent hours googling and constantly removing plists, yet i can't get it back. please help.

Version OSX 10.13.2

Answer (score 1):

Open `System Preferences > Network`,
select the appropriate location you want to configure. You might have only one named `Automatic` which is only for very basic configuration and shouldn’t be kept for different network usages.

Then down under the left window select the <kbd>+</kbd> button and choose the appropriate interface to recreate.